# Who is wrong about the http://0:port?

Tags: perl, lwp, psgi

The Plack suite commonly uses the `http://0:port`. E.g. the following

```
plackup -MPlack::App::Directory -e 'Plack::App::Directory->new(root=>".");'
```

prints

```
HTTP::Server::PSGI: Accepting connections at http://0:5000/
```

However, the `LWP::UserAgent` (or some deeper called modules) didn't accepts it, e.g. the:

```
perl -MLWP::UserAgent -E '$u=LWP::UserAgent->new;$res=$u->get("http://0:5000/valid/path");print $res->status_line'
```

prints:

```
500 No Host option provided
```

but the

```
perl -MLWP::UserAgent -E '$u=LWP::UserAgent->new;$res=$u->get("http://localhost:5000/valid/path");print $res->status_line'
```

prints

```
200 OK
```

The question is: who is wrong?

- Is the `http://0:port` valid, e.g. the LWP is "wrong"
- or it isn't valid and the PSGI uses it as only "randomly valid" shortcut?

Comment: Localhost is not address `0`, it's (typically) `127.0.0.1`. Try pinging `localhost` to see the actual address.

Comment: This is relevant: http://lists.scsys.co.uk/pipermail/catalyst/2012-April/028434.html

Comment: @JoachimPileborg ok, edited the question title. :) The question's merit is remain: the url `http://0:5000` is valid or no? Could/should be used or no?

Comment: Address `0` is the wildcard address used by servers when they want to listen to connections from all interfaces. It makes no sense trying to connect to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The output of the Plack suite is the output of a **server**. A server typically [`bind`s](http://linux.die.net/man/2/bind) a socket to a certain port and address in order to serve content there.
The notation `http://0:port` means in this case: *[listen](http://linux.die.net/man/2/listen) on port `port` on **all addresses** of this machine*. This is handy if you don't know or don't want to specify all addresses of the machine where the server should be reachable.

The output of the LWP::UserAgent ist the output of a **client**. In order to open a connection to a server, you **must** explicitly specify the address **and** the port to connect to. `0` is no valid IP address, therefore the connection fails when you [connect](http://linux.die.net/man/2/connect) to `http://0:port`.

Comment: The `http://0:port` is an *URL*. So, the `http://0:5000` isn't valid URL and it is "only" _handy_. Right?

Comment: it's no valid URL. It's just the result of a `printf` somewhere in the code of Plack. A server doesn't bind to a URL but to the combination of IP address and port.

Comment: okay, understand the bind - but the PSGI prints an *URL*, e.g. `http://0:5000` . ok - now know - it prints an invalid URL, but it is handy in many situations - many browsers just translates it to `127.0.0.1`.  Thanx. :)

Comment: While the answer is correct it should contain: the printed URL isn't valid. (and imho, using the `http://*:5000` would be more clear - however it isn't as handy as `0:5000`. :) +1 anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Safari 11, curl and wget resolve `http://0:5000` to `http://0.0.0.0:5000` and connect to the localhost.

I just tested it, after seeing the URL and finding the answer to the question dissatisfying.